# python (pandas) - TypeError: must be str, not list when concatenating lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, typeerror

I have this dataframe; please note the last column ("Yr_Mo_Date") on the right

```
In[38]: data.head()
Out[38]:
    RPT     VAL     ROS     KIL     SHA     BIR     DUB     CLA     MUL     CLO     BEL     MAL     Yr_Mo_Dy
0   15.04   14.96   13.17   9.29    NaN     9.87    13.67   10.25   10.83   12.58   18.50   15.04   61-1-1
1   14.71   NaN     10.83   6.50    12.62   7.67    11.50   10.04   9.79    9.67    17.54   13.83   61-1-2
2   18.50   16.88   12.33   10.13   11.17   6.17    11.25   NaN     8.50    7.67    12.75   12.71   61-1-3
3   10.58   6.63    11.75   4.58    4.54    2.88    8.63    1.79    5.83    5.88    5.46    10.88   61-1-4
4   13.33   13.25   11.42   6.17    10.71   8.21    11.92   6.54    10.92   10.34   12.92   11.83   61-1-5
```

The type of the "Yr_Mo_Dy" column is object while the others are float64.

I simply want to change the order of the columns so that "Yr_Mo_Dy" is the first column in the dataframe. 
I tried the following but I get TypeError. What's wrong?

```
In[39]: cols = data.columns.tolist()
In[40]: cols
Out[40]:
['RPT',
 'VAL',
 'ROS',
 'KIL',
 'SHA',
 'BIR',
 'DUB',
 'CLA',
 'MUL',
 'CLO',
 'BEL',
 'MAL',
 'Yr_Mo_Dy']
In[41]: cols = cols[-1] + cols[:-1]
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-c0130d1863e8> in <module>()
----> 1 cols = cols[-1] + cols[:-1]

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: col[-1] is of datatype string; col[1:] is of datatype list. You can only add a list to a list, not a string to a list.

Comment: `cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `:` for one element list because need concanecate 2 lists:

```
#string
print (cols[-1])
Yr_Mo_Dy

#one element list
print (cols[-1:])
['Yr_Mo_Dy']

cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
```

Or is possible add `[]`, but it is worse readable:

```
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
```

---

```
print (cols)
['Yr_Mo_Dy', 'RPT', 'VAL', 'ROS', 'KIL', 'SHA', 'BIR', 
 'DUB', 'CLA', 'MUL', 'CLO', 'BEL', 'MAL']
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't realize it extracted only a string, silly me... Btw I'm amazed how fast you always are with your responses, thanks so much. :)

Comment: I had same problem some time ago, so I remember solution ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use [**`pd.DataFrame.insert`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [**`pd.DataFrame.pop`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) to alter the dataframe in place.  This is a very generalizable solution as you can swap in any column position for popping or inserting.

```
c = df.columns[-1]
df.insert(0, c, df.pop(c))
df

  Yr_Mo_Dy    RPT    VAL    ROS    KIL    SHA   BIR    DUB    CLA    MUL    CLO    BEL    MAL
0   61-1-1  15.04  14.96  13.17   9.29    NaN  9.87  13.67  10.25  10.83  12.58  18.50  15.04
1   61-1-2  14.71    NaN  10.83   6.50  12.62  7.67  11.50  10.04   9.79   9.67  17.54  13.83
2   61-1-3  18.50  16.88  12.33  10.13  11.17  6.17  11.25    NaN   8.50   7.67  12.75  12.71
3   61-1-4  10.58   6.63  11.75   4.58   4.54  2.88   8.63   1.79   5.83   5.88   5.46  10.88
4   61-1-5  13.33  13.25  11.42   6.17  10.71  8.21  11.92   6.54  10.92  10.34  12.92  11.83
```

---

**Option 2**
[**`pd.DataFrame.reindex_axis`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) and [**`np.roll`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
df.reindex_axis(np.roll(df.columns, 1), 1)

  Yr_Mo_Dy    RPT    VAL    ROS    KIL    SHA   BIR    DUB    CLA    MUL    CLO    BEL    MAL
0   61-1-1  15.04  14.96  13.17   9.29    NaN  9.87  13.67  10.25  10.83  12.58  18.50  15.04
1   61-1-2  14.71    NaN  10.83   6.50  12.62  7.67  11.50  10.04   9.79   9.67  17.54  13.83
2   61-1-3  18.50  16.88  12.33  10.13  11.17  6.17  11.25    NaN   8.50   7.67  12.75  12.71
3   61-1-4  10.58   6.63  11.75   4.58   4.54  2.88   8.63   1.79   5.83   5.88   5.46  10.88
4   61-1-5  13.33  13.25  11.42   6.17  10.71  8.21  11.92   6.54  10.92  10.34  12.92  11.83
```

Comment: Interesting! So much simpler than what I was looking for! Will be using that in the future. Thank you!